# Unable to assign string to string data type in c++

Tags: c++, string, character

I'm trying to write a simple program to which takes away the spaces from a string as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    cout<< s;
    string c;
    int i =0,j=0;
    while(s[i]!='\0'){
        if(s[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        else{
            c[j] = s[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    c[j] ='\0';
    cout << c; //unable to print

 }
```

Here when I try to print c I can't  seem to be able to get a result. When I used c as a character array it worked but I'd still like to know what I was doing wrong. Thanks so much

Comment: `c` is an empty string. If you want to add to it, use `c += s[i];` You also do not need to null terminate it, and you would be better off using `s.size()` to know how long to iterate, or a range based for loop.

Comment: Off-topic, but what is "strings.h", and you should avoid using _bits/stdc++_, and instead just include what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
string c;
```

creates an empty string. After that,

```
c[j] = s[i];
```

is cause for undefined behavior.

You can solve the problem using many strategies. Here are a couple of them:

#### Construct `c` with large enough size

```
string c(s.size(), '\0');
```

#### Use `std::string::push_back`

Instead of

```
    c[j] = s[i];

    ...

c[j] ='\0';
```

use

```
    c.push_back(s[i]);

    ...

c.push_back('\0');
```